# How do I log initialize/end times in Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, sidekiq

I found these logs [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging) that I'm trying to duplicate in my code, specifically the `start` time and `done` times:

`PID-- ThreadID----- LLvl  YourKlass- JobID--------
TID-oveahmcxw INFO: HardWorker JID-oveaivtrg start
TID-oveajt7ro INFO: HardWorker JID-oveaish94 start

TID-oveahmcxw INFO: HardWorker JID-oveaivtrg done: 10.003 sec
TID-oveajt7ro INFO: HardWorker JID-oveaish94 done: 10.002 sec`

Does anyone know how to access these values? I know there is a `jid` that gets popluated (which I'm using), but I can't for the life of me find any documentation on where `start` and `done` come from.

Answer (score 0):

You can add logging by using a middleware:

```
class JobMiddleware
  def call(worker, msg, queue)
    Rails.logger.info "Job #{worker.jid} stated at #{Time.now}"
    yield
    Rails.logger.info "Job #{worker.jid} ended at #{Time.now}"
  end
end
```

Add this to `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` and restart your sidekiq workers.

[Click here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware) for more info about sidekiq middlewares